# Is it possible to generate a line graph for these variables?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a data set from:

```
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/17/breast+cancer+wisconsin+diagnostic
```

The variables are described in the data set as follows:

```
1) ID number 
2) Diagnosis (M = malignant, B = benign) 
3-32)
  a) radius (mean of distances from center to points on the perimeter)
  b) texture (standard deviation of gray-scale values)
  c) perimeter
  d) area
  e) smoothness (local variation in radius lengths)
  f) compactness (perimeter^2 / area - 1.0)
  g) concavity (severity of concave portions of the contour)
  h) concave points (number of concave portions of the contour)
  i) symmetry 
  j) fractal dimension ("coastline approximation" - 1)
```

**Is it possible to generate a line plot for any variables from this data set?**
I personally think that it is not possible, but how to justify it.